# aws lambda c++ runtime seg fault (but works locally)

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to get a simple example running on aws c++ runtime, but it keeps seg faulting when I invoke the lambda function. To start with, the example shown in: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/ works fine. So, now, I fetch something from a bucket like so:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/client/ClientConfiguration.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.h>
#include <awsdoc/s3/s3_examples.h>
#include <vector>
#include <rapidcsv.h>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <torch/script.h> // One-stop header.
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory>
#include <aws/lambda-runtime/runtime.h>

using namespace torch::indexing;
using namespace Aws::Utils;
using namespace aws::lambda_runtime;

char const TAG[] = "LAMBDA_ALLOC";

static invocation_response my_handler(invocation_request const &req)
{
   if (req.payload.length() > 42)
   {
      return invocation_response::failure("error message here" /*error_message*/,
                                          "error type here" /*error_type*/);
   }

   Aws::SDKOptions options;
   Aws::InitAPI(options);

   const Aws::String bucket_name("buckname");
   const Aws::String object_name("fname");

   Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client;
   Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
   object_request.SetBucket(bucket_name);
   object_request.SetKey(object_name);
   Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome get_object_outcome =

   s3_client.GetObject(object_request);
   auto &retrieved_file = get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody();
   rapidcsv::Document doc(retrieved_file, rapidcsv::LabelParams(-1, -1)); /// this is where the problem is.

   const Aws::String objectKey2("model.tar");
   Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client2;
   Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request2;
   object_request2.SetBucket(bucket_name);
   object_request2.SetKey(objectKey2);
   Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome get_object_outcome2 =
   s3_client2.GetObject(object_request2);
   auto &retrieved_file2 = get_object_outcome2.GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody();

   torch::jit::script::Module module;
   module = torch::jit::load(retrieved_file2);  /// this is also where the problem is.
   std::cout << "Model Load ok\n";

   Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

   return invocation_response::success(tensor_string /*payload*/,
                                       "application/json" /*MIME type*/);
}

int main()
{

   run_handler(my_handler);
   return 0;
}
```

the thing is, it compiles and works as expected when I run it locally (debian, cmake), but when I compile it for aws runtime, I get the seg fault.

I have narrowed down the problem to two lines:

```
rapidcsv::Document doc(retrieved_file, rapidcsv::LabelParams(-1, -1)); /// this is where the problem is.
```

and also,

```
module = torch::jit::load(retrieved_file2);  /// this is also where the problem is.
```

I use the rapidcsv header only lib from here: https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv and as I said, it works fine locally.

I suspect somehow the runtime is not able to find rapidcsv (but that still fails to explain why it seg faults on `module = torch::jit::load(retrieved_file2);` :(

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Doesn't `get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership()` return RAII object (so destroyed mostly immediatly), making `auto &retrieved_file` dangling reference?

Comment: example seems to use `GetResult()` instead.

Comment: @JaI will try this right away.. but how come it works locally?

Comment: @Jarod42: can you point me to where `getResult()` is used please?

Comment: @Jarod42 yea I see it in doc: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp/blob/master/examples/s3/main.cpp

Comment: @Jarod42 hmm unfortunately changing to `get_object_outcome2.GetResult().GetBody();` dosent solve the seg fault :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little bit late to provide input now, but anyway in case someone encounters similar problems with rapidcsv on AWS Lambda:

One potential difference between local and AWS is the available RAM. By following the [basic tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime) one ends up with a lambda function with 128 MB RAM (`aws lambda create-function ... --memory-size 128`). Depending on the data size to process, this may on the low side.

In the AWS Lambda console it's possible to test run a lambda function and see the configured and max memory used, for example:

```
Resources configured   128 MB
Max memory used        44 MB
```

It might be worth checking that the max usage is below configured level.